# Create a datagridview cell which can contain several clickable links?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to have a column/cell in a DataGridView which can contain multiple links each of which is individually clickable?

Example mocked up in Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code for [DataGridViewLinkCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcell.aspx) class using a tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). I would imagine you'd need to create your own datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcell and possibly your own editing control. ([Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881.aspx) has a detailed example of this).

- you'll need to override the [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.paint.aspx) method to paint links horizontally.
- You'll need to use the cell's font to create a new one with the [Underline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.underline.aspx) property set to true.
- You'll also need to override the [OnMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.onmousemove.aspx) to change the cursor when it's over the link.
- You'll need to override the [OnMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.onmousedown.aspx) to determine which link they clicked

Again, the DataGridViewLinkCell does all of these for a single link plus more, so I would use that code for the class as a starting point for your needs.

Comment: your answer is both awesome and depressing, I was hoping there was an out-of-the-box solution to this problem :-(